# Mock HttpClient using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest, dotnet-httpclient

I would like to unit test a class that uses `HttpClient`. We injected the `HttpClient` object in the class constructor.

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ClassA(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequest(SomeObject someObject)
    {
        //Do some stuff

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://some-domain.in");

        //Build the request

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Now we would like to unit test the `ClassA.SendRequest` method. We are using `Ms Test` for unit testing framework and `Moq` for mocking.

When we tried to mock the `HttpClient`, it throws `NotSupportedException`.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SendRequestAsync_Test()
{
    var mockHttpClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();

    mockHttpClient.Setup(
        m => m.SendAsync(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>()))
    .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)));
}
```

How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That particular overload method is not virtual so is unable to be overridden by Moq.

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request);
```

Which is why it throws `NotSupportedException`

The virtual method you are looking for is this method

```
public virtual Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

However mocking `HttpClient` is not as simple as it seems with its internal message handler.

I suggest using a concrete client with a custom message handler stub that will allow for more flexibility when faking the request.

Here is an example of a delegating handler stub.

```
public class DelegatingHandlerStub : DelegatingHandler {
    private readonly Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> _handlerFunc;
    public DelegatingHandlerStub() {
        _handlerFunc = (request, cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }

    public DelegatingHandlerStub(Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> handlerFunc) {
        _handlerFunc = handlerFunc;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return _handlerFunc(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Note the default constructor is doing basically what you were trying to mock before. It also allows for more custom scenarios with a delegate for the request.

With the stub, the test can be refactored to something like

```
public async Task _SendRequestAsync_Test() {
    //Arrange           
    var handlerStub = new DelegatingHandlerStub();
    var client = new HttpClient(handlerStub);
    var sut = new ClassA(client);
    var obj = new SomeObject() {
        //Populate
    };

    //Act
    var response = await sut.SendRequest(obj);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Moq can mock out protected methods, such as SendAsync on the HttpMessageHandler that you can provide to HttpClient in its constructor.

```cs
var mockHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
     });

var client = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object);
```

Copied from https://www.thecodebuzz.com/unit-test-mock-httpclientfactory-moq-net-core/

Answer (score 10):

I recently had to mock HttpClient, and I used [Moq.Contrib.HttpClient](https://github.com/maxkagamine/Moq.Contrib.HttpClient).  It was what I needed, and simple to use, so I thought I'd throw it out there.

Here is an example  of general usage:

```
// All requests made with HttpClient go through its handler's SendAsync() which we mock
var handler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
var client = handler.CreateClient();

// A simple example that returns 404 for any request
handler.SetupAnyRequest()
    .ReturnsResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

// Match GET requests to an endpoint that returns json (defaults to 200 OK)
handler.SetupRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "https://example.com/api/stuff")
    .ReturnsResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), "application/json");

// Setting additional headers on the response using the optional configure action
handler.SetupRequest("https://example.com/api/stuff")
    .ReturnsResponse(bytes, configure: response =>
    {
        response.Content.Headers.LastModified = new DateTime(2018, 3, 9);
    })
    .Verifiable(); // Naturally we can use Moq methods as well

// Verify methods are provided matching the setup helpers
handler.VerifyAnyRequest(Times.Exactly(3));
```

For more info, check out author's blog post [here](https://kagamine.dev/en/mock-httpclient-the-easy-way/).

Comment: Amazing! helps me in multi-request-response scenario - .NET 6.0

Answer (score 8):

Propper mocking with HttpClient is hard work as it was written before most people did unit testing in dotnet. Sometimes I setup a stub HTTP server that returns canned responses based on pattern matching the request url, meaning you test real HTTP requests not mocks but to a localhost server. Using [WireMock.net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) makes this really easy and runs fast enough to satisfy most of my unit testing needs.

So instead of `http://some-domain.in` use a localhost server setup on some port, and then:

```
var server = FluentMockServer.Start(/*server and port can be setup here*/);
server.Given(
      Request.Create()
      .WithPath("/").UsingPost()
   )
   .RespondWith(
       Response.Create()
       .WithStatusCode(200)
       .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
       .WithBody("{'attr':'value'}")
   );
```

You can find a more details and [guidance on using wiremock in tests here.](https://alastaircrabtree.com/stubbing-your-way-to-automated-e2e-testing-api-first-with-wiremock/)