# Unit Testing Core API Controller Using Custom HttpClient and Polly policy within ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have problems performing unit testing when using `Polly` and `HttpClient`.

Specifically, Polly and HttpClient are used for ASP.NET Core Web API Controller following the links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests

https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory

The problems (1 and 2) are specified at the bottom. I wonder if this is the correct way to using `Polly` and `HttpClient`.

**ConfigureServices**

Configure Polly policy and sepecify custom HttpClient, `CustomHttpClient`

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddHttpClient();
   services.AddHttpClient<HttpClientService>()                                
                .AddPolicyHandler((service, request) =>
                    HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
                        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
                            retryCount => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryCount)))
                );
 }
```

**CarController**

CarController depends on `HttpClientService`, which is injected by the framework automatically without explicit registration.

Please note that `HttpClientService` causes issues with unit test as `Moq` cannot mock a non virtual method, which is mentioned later on.

```
 [ApiVersion("1")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CarController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILog _logger;
        private readonly HttpClientService _httpClientService;
        private readonly IOptions<Config> _config;

        public CarController(ILog logger, HttpClientService httpClientService, IOptions<Config> config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClientService = httpClientService;
            _config = config;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post()
        {  

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string body = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    var statusCode = await _httpClientService.PostAsync(
                        "url",
                        new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            {"headerID", "Id"}                           
                        },
                        body);
                    return StatusCode((int)statusCode);               
            }
        }
      }
```

**HttpClientService**

Simiar to `CarController`, `HttpClientService` has an issue with Unit test, because `HttpClient`'s PostAsync cannot be mocked. `HttpClient` is injected by the framework automatically without explicit registration.

```
 public class HttpClientService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public HttpClientService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<HttpStatusCode> PostAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> headers, string body)
    {
        using (var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {
            foreach (var keyValue in headers)
            {
                content.Headers.Add(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
            }

            var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, content);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return response.StatusCode;
        }

    }
```

**Problem 1**

Unit Test: `Moq` cannot mock `HttpClientService`'s `PostAsync` method. I CAN change it to virtual, but I wonder if it is the best option.

```
public class CarControllerTests
    {
        private readonly Mock<ILog> _logMock;
        private readonly Mock<HttpClient> _httpClientMock;
        private readonly Mock<HttpClientService> _httpClientServiceMock;
        private readonly Mock<IOptions<Config>> _optionMock;
        private readonly CarController _sut;


        public CarControllerTests()  //runs for each test method
        {
            _logMock = new Mock<ILog>();
            _httpClientMock = new Mock<HttpClient>();
            _httpClientServiceMock = new Mock<HttpClientService>(_httpClientMock.Object);
            _optionMock = new Mock<IOptions<Config>>();
            _sut = new CarController(_logMock.Object, _httpClientServiceMock.Object, _optionMock.Object);
        }

            [Fact]
               public void Post_Returns200()
            {
                    //System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member
                        _httpClientServiceMock.Setup(hc => hc.PostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(),
                        It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(),
                        It.IsAny<string>()))
                    .Returns(Task.FromResult(HttpStatusCode.OK));
                    }
             }


}
```

**Problem 2**

Unit test: similar to `HttpClientService`,  `Moq` cannot mock `HttpClient`'s `PostAsync` method.

```
  public class HttpClientServiceTests
{
        [Fact]
           public void Post_Returns200()
        {

            var httpClientMock = new Mock<HttpClient>();

            //System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member
        httpClientMock.Setup(hc => hc.PostAsync("", It.IsAny<HttpContent>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage()));
            }

}
```

ASP.NET Core API 2.2

**Update**

Corrected a typo of CustomHttpClient to HttpClientService

**Update 2**

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715602/mock-httpclient-using-moq/44716910#44716910) to problem 2

Comment: The controller is tightly coupled to implementation concerns which as you have already experiences are difficult to test in isolation (unit test).  Encapsulate those concretions behind abstractions that can be replaced when testing.

Comment: Is `CustomHttpClient` the `HttpClientService` in this example? typo?

Comment: Corrected the typo, please see my update and comment to your answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `CustomHttpClient` is a typo an the `HttpClientService` is the actual dependency, the controller is tightly coupled to implementation concerns which, as you have already experiences, are difficult to test in isolation (unit test).

Encapsulate those concretions behind abstractions

```
public interface IHttpClientService {
    Task<HttpStatusCode> PostAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> headers, string body);
}


public class HttpClientService : IHttpClientService {
    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

that can be replaced when testing.

Refactor the controller to depend on the abstraction and not the concrete implementation

```
public class CarController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly ILog _logger;
    private readonly IHttpClientService httpClientService; //<-- TAKE NOTE
    private readonly IOptions<Config> _config;

    public CarController(ILog logger, IHttpClientService httpClientService, IOptions<Config> config) {
        _logger = logger;
        this.httpClientService = httpClientService;
        _config = config;
    }

    //...omitted for brevity

}
```

Update the service configuration to use the overload that allows the registration of the abstraction along with its implementation

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services
        .AddHttpClient<IHttpClientService, HttpClientService>() //<-- TAKE NOTE
        .AddPolicyHandler((service, request) =>
            HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
                    retryCount => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryCount)))
        );
}
```

That takes care of refatcoring the code to make it more test friendly.

The following shows how the controller can now be unit tested in isolation

```
public class CarControllerTests {
    private readonly Mock<ILog> _logMock;
    private readonly Mock<IHttpClientService> _httpClientServiceMock;
    private readonly Mock<IOptions<Config>> _optionMock;
    private readonly CarController _sut;


    public CarControllerTests()  //runs for each test method 
    {
        _logMock = new Mock<ILog>();
        _httpClientServiceMock = new Mock<IHttpClientService>();
        _optionMock = new Mock<IOptions<Config>>();
        _sut = new CarController(_logMock.Object, _httpClientServiceMock.Object, _optionMock.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Post_Returns200() {
        //Arrange
        _httpClientServiceMock
            .Setup(_ => _.PostAsync(
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(),
                It.IsAny<string>())
            )
            .ReturnsAsync(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        //Act

        //...omitted for brevity

        //...
    }
}
```

Note how there was no longer a need for the `HttpClient` for the test to be exercised to completion.

There are other dependencies that the controller will need to make sure are arranged for the test to flow but that is currently ouside of the scope of the question.

Comment: Great, what about HttpClientServiceTests? which is problem 2 caused by HttpClient not being able to be mocked by Moq.

Comment: @Pingpong review https://stackoverflow.com/a/44716910/5233410 for help with the testing with HttpClient dependency