# When using HttpClientFactory in c#, how can I test the Http call being made?

Tags: c#, http, integration-testing, dotnet-httpclient

I have a `SessionService` that has `HttpClient` injected into it and is registered as a **Typed Client**
[See Microsoft example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

I want to be able to write an integration test that I can control the responses made when the HttpClient is used.

I think that passing in a `HttpMessageHandler` to the `HttpClient` will allow me to intercept the request and control the response.

The problem I have is that I can't seem to add the `HttpMessageHandler` to the existing `HttpClientFactory` registration

```
// My client
public class SessionService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public SessionService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<Session> GetAsync(string id)
    {
        var httpResponseMessage = await this.httpClient.GetAsync($"session/{id}");
        var responseJson = await httpResponseMessage.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Session>(responseJson);
    }
}
```

```
// Live registrations
public static class HttpModule
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddHttpModule(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection) =>
        serviceCollection
            .AddHttpClient<SessionService>()
            .Services;
}
```

```
// My HttpMessageHandler which controls the response
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        // customise response

        return response;
    }
}
```

If I try re-register the Typed Client so I can add the `HttpMessageHandler` it tells me I've already registered the client and can't register it again.

```
public static class TestHttpModule
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTestHttpModule(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection) =>
        serviceCollection
            .AddHttpClient<SessionService>() // <== Errors
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<FakeHttpMessageHandler>()
            .Services;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: All the different calls to HttpClient  eventually call `.Send` which is mockable.

Comment: How to you inject the mock if the HttpClient has been registered already?

Comment: You can mock/moq HttpClient like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227487/how-to-mock-the-new-httpclientfactory-in-net-core-2-1-using-moq although I'd question if this is suitable for integration testing.

Comment: @Neil, thanks for the response, I think that using a Mocked HttpClient would have the same issue.  If I can inject a different HttpClient, then I can also inject a HttpClient with the HttpMessageHandler that I want to use.

Comment: *I can't seem to add the HttpMessageHandler to the existing HttpClientFactory registration* create your own factory then?

Comment: When I register a HttpClient using `.AddHttpClient()` it registers the HttpClient to an internal dictionary and I can't seem to remove it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because when you register a HttpClient using Dependency Injection, it adds it to an internal `HttpClientMappingRegistry` class.  The fix was to remove the registration for the registry class.  This allows me to re-add the Typed client and specify a HttpMessageHandler

```
public static class TestHttpModule
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTestHttpModule(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection) =>
        serviceCollection
            .AddSingleton(typeof(FakeHttpMessageHandler))
            .RemoveHttpClientRegistry()
            .AddHttpClient<SessionService>()
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<FakeHttpMessageHandler>()
            .Services;

    private static IServiceCollection RemoveHttpClientRegistry(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        var registryType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == "HttpClientMappingRegistry");
        var descriptor = serviceCollection.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ServiceType == registryType);

        if (descriptor != null)
        {
            serviceCollection.Remove(descriptor);
        }

        return serviceCollection;
    }
}
```