# Net Core testing method with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, moq

I have a service method that does a request using `HttpClient`. The service class constructor injects `IHttpClientFactory` and creates the client using this code:

```
_httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(url);
```

In my test constructor I am trying to mock the `PostAsync` method response.

```
public MyServiceUnitTests()
    {
        _HttpClientMock = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
        var mockHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
        mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected()
            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("PostAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<string>(), ItExpr.IsAny<HttpContent>())
            .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage{ StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK });
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object);
        _HttpClientMock.Setup(x => x.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(httpClient);

        _Service = new MyService(_HttpClientMock.Object);
    }
```

I am getting the following error when setting up the mockHttpMessageHandler: `System.ArgumentException: 'No protected method HttpMessageHandler.PostAsync found whose signature is compatible with the provided arguments (string, HttpContent).'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can check similar implementation in the rated answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425008/mocking-httpclient-in-unit-tests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking HttpMessageHandler with moq - How do I get the contents of the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413738/mocking-httpmessagehandler-with-moq-how-do-i-get-the-contents-of-the-request)

Comment: Please also check [this article](https://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/08/mock-httpclient-using-httpmessagehandler/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `PostAsync` method on the handler.

You need to mock [SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler.sendasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpMessageHandler_SendAsync_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)