# Cannot reslove symbol 'CreateResponse'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, delegates, nunit, asp.net-core-3.1

i want to unit test a repository that uses the the HttpClientFactory.i asked the question [how do i unit test a repo that calls IHttpClientFactory with Nunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750427/how-do-i-unit-test-a-repo-that-calls-ihttpclientfactory-with-nunit). Helpful enough someone suggested i check a similar question which was asked at [How to mock the new HttpClientFactory in .NET Core 2.1 using Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715602/mock-httpclient-using-moq/44716910#44716910).
Following the suggested solution,i stumbled another problem,a method in the most voted answer to the question is not working.
the line of code in solution is

`_handlerFunc = (request, cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));`

The method `request.CreateResponse` seems that it does not exist for the request object.Am using asp.netcore 3.1

Answer (score 0):

[`CreateResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is an extension method that uses the request to create a corresponding response.

You could forego that extension method and create the `HttpResponseMessage` manually.

```
_handlerFunc = (request, cancellationToken) => 
    Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK });`
```

Comment: Thanks i just did that.now am having problems with ``new HttpConfiguration()`` it seems its under System.Web.Http Namespace which was supported in asp.net core2.1 and am using asp.netcore 3.1.please help am really stuck with these tests..nothing seems to be working

Comment: @DavidTembo remove `HttpConfiguration` if you are creating the response manually. It wont be needed. It was there because the extension method needed it.

Comment: So how can i arrange the tests without the extension method. without the extension method i get the error   `` An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PrepareRequestMessage``